# Limit by sum of column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get limited records from my database according to a max sum count of a column.
The table:

```
| id | count | name        |
|----|-------|-------------|
| 1  | 5     | Berlin      |
| 2  | 4     | New York    |
| 3  | 2     | Minsk       |
| 4  | 2     | London      |
```

The max count of the sum of the count column should not exceed 4 but should contain atleast one record.

Expected Output: (after each fetch, delete the item from table)

```
#1
| id | count | name        |
|----|-------|-------------|
| 1  | 5     | Berlin      |

#2
| id | count | name        |
|----|-------|-------------|
| 2  | 4     | New York    |

#3
| id | count | name        |
|----|-------|-------------|
| 3  | 2     | Minsk       |
| 4  | 2     | London      |
```

I tried it according to this thread: [at forums.mysql.com](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,244913) but it didn't actually worked.

I tried:

```sql
SET @sum=0;
SELECT id, count, @sum:=@sum + count as running_count FROM cities HAVING @sum <= 4;
```

EDIT:
That comes it near.

```sql
WITH data as (
 SELECT *, sum(count) over (order by id) as running FROM cities
)

SELECT * FROM data WHERE running <= 4
```

Comment: You lost me at 'count of the sum of the count'

Comment: sorry, not native. Hope you understand it anyway. Have a great day.

Comment: So how does Berlin satisfy the criteria?

Comment: It should not exceed 4 but contain at least 1 record. But thats basically not as important for me.

Comment: Looks like the problem of linear cutting. This cannot be solved effectively on SQL.

Comment: Is it not the same as what this gentleman does? https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,244913,244963#msg-244963 I think I have to little understanding of how sql parses tables.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version. Does you need in optimal solution (minimized amount of groups) or any solution?

Comment: MySQL 8.0.21. 
Not really. Later I want to add SKIP LOCKED functionallity – so any solution would be fine.

Comment: I would be wary of referencing code from over a decade ago, regardless of the gentlemanliness of the author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH data as (
  SELECT
     *,
     sum(count) over (order by id) as running
  FROM
     cities
     
)

SELECT 
   *
FROM
   data
WHERE 
   (running <= 4) OR
   (running = (SELECT min(running) FROM data)
```

Gets me the result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `id` determines the order, you can get the "first" record using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.count,
       t1.name
       FROM elbat t1
       ORDER BY t1.id
       LIMIT 1;
```

You can then `UNION` all the records whose `count`s don't exceed the limit when summed. In MySQL 8+ you can use the `sum()` window function for that.

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.count,
       x.name
       FROM (SELECT t2.id,
                    t2.count,
                    t2.name,
                    sum(t2.count) OVER (ORDER BY id) sum_count
                    FROM elbat t2) x
       WHERE x.sum_count <= 4;
```

Prior version 8 you can use a correlated subquery and aggregation.

```
SELECT t2.id,
       t2.count,
       t2.name
       FROM elbat t2
       WHERE (SELECT sum(t3.count)
                     FROM elbat t3
                     WHERE t3.id <= t2.id) <= 4;
```

All in all this gets you

```
(SELECT t1.id,
        t1.count,
        t1.name
        FROM elbat t1
        ORDER BY t1.id
        LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT x.id,
        x.count,
        x.name
        FROM (SELECT t2.id,
                     t2.count,
                     t2.name,
                     sum(t2.count) OVER (ORDER BY id) sum_count
                     FROM elbat t2) x
        WHERE x.sum_count <= 4);
```

for 8+ and

```
(SELECT t1.id,
        t1.count,
        t1.name
        FROM elbat t1
        ORDER BY t1.id
        LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT t2.id,
        t2.count,
        t2.name
        FROM elbat t2
        WHERE (SELECT sum(t3.count)
                      FROM elbat t3
                      WHERE t3.id <= t2.id) <= 4);
```

for 8-.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=945acfa679f966ae5d92b3f8db53142d)